# Call upon individual bins in histograms in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I need to use each individual bin of three histograms to use in an equation (i.e. bin1 from histogram1, histogram2, and histogram3, and then bin2 from h1, h2, h3, etc).

Is there any way to call the individual bins from a histogram to use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example chart that looks like what you want to do?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that gives people a start to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you call `plt.hist` the locations of the bins, as well as the number of entries in each bin is returned. Let's say you generated three histograms (I'm going to go for histograms 0, 1 and 2, because python):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x0 = np.random.rand(25)
x1 = np.random.rand(25)
x2 = np.random.rand(25)

counts0, bins0, patches0 = plt.hist(x0)
counts1, bins1, patches1 = plt.hist(x1)
counts2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(x2)
```

The locations of the bins for histogram 0 are then stored in `bins0`.

The number of entries in the bins of histogram 0 is then stored in `counts0`.

I'd then be tempted to gather these together into 2d arrays:

```py
counts = np.vstack([counts0, counts1, counts2]).T
bins = np.vstack([bins0, bins1, bins2]).T
```

Now, `bins[i, j]` details the location of bin `i` for histogram `j`. Similarly `counts[i, j]` contains the number of entries in bin `i` of histogram `j`.

With this set up you can get the counts in bin `i` for histograms 0, 1 and 2 as `counts[i]`.

Additionally, if you don't actually *need* the plots, and are only calling `plt.hist` to get a handle on `counts` and `bins` then you can use `np.histogram` instead. The syntax is similar: `counts, bins = np.histogram(x)` (`np.histogram`  doesn't return patches).